# Find a part of a word from a text file, and print the whole word By PHP

Tags: php, string, search

Can somebody help me to find a part of a word from a text file and then print the whole word with php?
like this, the test.txt has the following texts,

```
book.physics.class12
disk.chemistry.class11 some random text........
book.math.class12 bla bla
```

Now I need to find class12, I need the output like

book.physics.class12
book.math.class12

anyone help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the contents of the file you need to use `php's` `get_file_contents` function => [**get_file_contents**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php).

After getting the contents of the file you need to use `preg_match_all` => [**preg_match_all**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)
to match all occurances of the defined pattern.

Then use a `foreach` loop => [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through the matches and return every value separately.

Here is the full code =>

```
$str = file_get_contents("path to the file");

preg_match_all('/\b[\w\.]+class12\b/',$str,$matches);

foreach($matches as $match){

foreach($match as $m){

        echo $m.'<br>';

        }

    }
```

Also read about regular expressions => [**Regular Expressions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)